# Android black-box testing (no access to app code). Is Google's Espresso a good choice?

Tags: android, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing, android-espresso

I have recently been looking in to `Espresso`, which looks for me very promising.

I am recently working in an Android test project, and we are recently using `Espresso` as we see some benefits with that. Unfortunately the setup in the company I work for is such that I do not have access to the entire code for the Application we are testing.

So how I can create a test using android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIAutomator to get the ids of various views.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOab0.jpg)

With view ids you can perform assertions/click and other actions on them

An example

```
onView(withId(R.id.play_search_container)).perform(click());
```

Hence you can go through the whole UI flow by clicking on various elements.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that i dont know how to create a test project outside my android application's code

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write a test outside of application's code, I mean: pure black-boxing, `Espresso` would be a pretty hard to implement as it needs a bit of application architecture (the same thing is with `Robotium` or `UiAutomator): names of Activities, views texts, contentDescriptions or idies.

You can use instead of `Espresso`:

- [`UI/Application Exerciser Monkey`](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html)

> The `Monkey` is a program that runs on your emulator or device and
>   generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks,
>   touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-level events. You
>   can use the Monkey to stress-test applications that you are
>   developing, in a random yet repeatable manner.

- [`monkeyrunner`](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html)(requires Python language programming basics)

> The `monkeyrunner` tool provides an API for writing programs that
>   control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code.
>   With `monkeyrunner`, you can write a `Python` program that installs an
>   Android application or test package, runs it, sends keystrokes to it,
>   takes screenshots of its user interface, and stores screenshots on the
>   workstation. 
>   The `monkeyrunner` tool is primarily designed to test
>   applications and devices at the functional/framework level and for
>   running unit test suites, but you are free to use it for other
>   purposes.

- [`Calabash`](http://calaba.sh/)

> `Calabash` is a framework that enables Automated UI Acceptance Tests
>   written in `Cucumber` to be run on iOS and Android applications.
>   Calabash works by enabling automatic UI interactions within an
>   application such as pressing buttons, entering text, validating
>   responses, etc.
>
> From: [Introduction to
>   Calabash](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/introduction-to-calabash/)

Hope it will help

Comment: I've recently stumbled upon [Atmosphere](http://atmosphereframework.com/). I think it is very well suited for Android blackbox testing and it's installation is very easy.